# ng-repeat highlight all rows but also deselect, select

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a basic html table where i need to have all the rows initially highlighted when the table is created. Also, if the user clicks the row it un highlights and clicked again highlights.

I have the click on a row, and it highlights. If you click again it un highlights.
I just need to initially highlight all rows possibly by ng-repeat. It also needs to release the highlighting when the row is clicked again and then highlight back. userData is just a line of text for each row

**HTML**

```
<table class="superusertable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody class="table-font">
  <tr ng-init="" ng-repeat="source in userData" 
                 ng-model="source.fromSourceID" 
                 ng-class="{'sourcesSelected': source.sourcesSelected}" 
                 ng-click="select(source)">
  <td width="290px">
 <div class="action-checkbox"; width="290px">{{source.fromSourceID}}
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**angular**

```
 $scope.select = function(item) {
    item.sourcesSelected ? item.sourcesSelected = false : item.sourcesSelected = true;
};
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is but your code is really verbose and confusing. Just write `item.sourcesSelected = !item.sourcesSelected;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a function to the `ng-init` attribute on your tr. Just pass in your item and set it to true. Then like Aluan said in a comment, you can just make your `ng-click` function simpler by doing `item.sourcesSelected = !item.sourcesSelected`.

html

```
<table class="superusertable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody class="table-font">
        <tr ng-init="init(source)" 
            ng-repeat="source in userData" 
            ng-model="source.fromSourceID" 
            ng-class="{'sourcesSelected': source.sourcesSelected}" 
            ng-click="select(source)">
            <td width="290px">
                <div class="action-checkbox"; width="290px">{{source.fromSourceID}}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

angular

```
$scope.select = function(item) {
    item.sourcesSelected = !item.sourcesSelected;
};

$scope.init = function(item) {
    item.sourcesSelected = true;
}
```

---

On a side note, you can completely eliminate the `ng-init` and `init` function by setting `item.sourcesSelected = true` when you are retrieving your data.

Comment: i actually figured it out and was putting it in an edit when this answer came in. I used ng-init="highlightRows(source)" but i will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

There are too many errors i can observe.

1. ng-init="" not required
2. ternary operator is wrong you should do something following:

   item.sourcesSelected = item.sourcesSelected ? false : true;